# Access error trying to create Azure service bus queue

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I'm running the following code in a simple console application that has the latest version of the WindowsAzure.ServiceBus NuGet package installed:

```
        var connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://<servername>/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=<SharedAccessKey>";
        var queueName = "TestQueue";

        var ns = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

        if (!ns.QueueExists(queueName))
            ns.CreateQueue(queueName);
```

And receiving the following error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024891
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. InvalidSignature: The token has an invalid signature. TrackingId:<GUID>_G30, SystemTracker:<MyQueue>.servicebus.windows.net
```

I tried a lot of different things to attempt to fix it including dropping and recreating the entire namespace.  I've also verified that the SharedAccessKey has the proper claims (i.e. Manage).

[image]

## Update

After coming back in the morning to continue troubleshooting this problem, it has mysteriously started working, so I guess the question has changed to, what happened here?  The code didn't change.  The key didn't change.  (Confused!)

Comment: I (barely) remember that are also some other ways to get namespace, not only via one connection string. Did you have the same error trying different approach?

Comment: I'll have a look around and see.  We've been using this approach without any problem until just now.

Comment: From my experience, Azure has sometimes backward compatibility issues. So cases when something is stop working in the newest library/service are maybe not common but appearing from time to time.

Comment: Just tried the same code with package version 3.4.3(latest), no problem. Your error says invalid signature, it must be something wrong with the shared access key I think. Did you get the string from portal?

Comment: @forester123 thank you for trying.  Yes, copy and pasted the string.  I agree, the string must be invalid in some way.  We've tried regenerating the key and using the secondary key.  Nothing seems to work.

Comment: I just tried this from my home laptop (as opposed to my work desktop) and everything worked as well.  Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you've got with `TrackingId:<GUID>_G30` indicates an issue on the gateway MSFT support team should be able to help with. Namespace management operations are going over HTTPS, I assume you have that opened, i.e. nothing is blocking it. So my bet would be to talk to Azure support, provide them with the `TrackingId` to figure out why the gateway turned your request down.

Comment: This seems like the most likely answer since the problem magically disappeared after a while.